# memset on x86 effects cache according to buffer size?

Tags: caching, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, dma

I'm allocating a buffer of 32MB using `malloc()` and `memset()` it with some data. When I use this buffer and pass it to a DMA driver where it uses `get_user_pages_fast()` to pin pages. When DMA operation is carried out the data is reaching peripheral.

But if I allocated a buffer of 8kB or 16kB or 32kB or 512kB, after DMA, stale data is being reached to the peripheral.

I tried above buffer sizes to allocate in driver using `dma_alloc_coherent()` and flushed the allocated addresses (using `clflush_cache_range()`) , then data is reaching End point, if do not flush data using above API data is not reaching.

So I have x86 machine which uses i7-3930K Intel processor which has 12MB smart cache.

So some how this issue looks like cache effects, but I don't have proper theory with user space why 32 MB buffer allocated and transmitted is being DMA properly.

Any guidance/help would give me better insight.